# Extending squeak or pharo

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, squeak, package-management

Using Monticello package manager does not seem to guarantee that, once you added the interesting package(s), the total image is still coherent. Are there any ways to verify that? Are dependencies verified? Are there guidelines in that direction?

Comment: Please accept one of the answers or ask for whatever information is missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for *Metacello*, a package and configuration manager for Monticello.

You can check out this guide: [Managing projects with Metacello](https://gforge.inria.fr/frs/download.php/28462/Metacello.pdf), and also there's a page on [Google code](http://code.google.com/p/metacello/)

Answer (score 1):

While Monticello actually has the possibility to ensure that dependencies are met, 
it is limited to the form “this Monticello version depends on exactly these other Monticello versions”. Also, specifying these dependencies is a bit hidden in the Monticello browser and, above all, scarcely used in the community.

As Uko said, [Metacello](https://code.google.com/p/metacello/) is exactly intended to solve the problem of dependency management in Smalltalk systems. It is *not* limited to Monticello, conceptually. To my knowledge, most GemStone, Pharo, and Squeak images come with Metacello pre-installed or easily installable.

Have a look at the [blog of Metacello’s author](http://gemstonesoup.wordpress.com/metacello-101/), Dale Henrichs, where he gives some introduction to using Metacello.

There is also the [Metacello Repository](http://www.squeaksource.com/MetacelloRepository/), where most configurations (think software receipts) can be found.

Answer (score 0):

Monticello's responsibility ends with loading individual packages. Coherence comes with either Metacello (see [Uko's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14551974/10259)) or with [SqueakMap](http://map.squeak.org).

SqueakMap stores install scripts that ensure that [entire](http://map.squeak.org/package/00e786be-3742-4976-be5b-ddfb6b51aeda) [applications](http://map.squeak.org/package/e02a34a1-aefc-4b39-9c30-eb25bbdaccd4) get loaded into your image.